# Finding the terminal velocity using limits in calculus.

Tags: calculus

So I'm tasked with finding the terminal velocity of a base jumper, which is defined as $\operatorname{lim v(t)}\limits_{t \to \infty}$ = $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty}$ $\sqrt{\frac{mg}{k}}\tanh(\sqrt{\frac{mg}{k}} * t)$

I know that the answer to this problem ends up beings $\sqrt{\frac{mg}{k}}$, but I'm not sure how to reach the answer. Is it a matter of integrals and derivative's, or something more? Any kind of help on how to approach this would be appreciated.

For reference, velocity is equal to $v(t) =\sqrt{\frac{mg}{k}}\tanh(\sqrt{\frac{mg}{k}} * t)$

Distance is equal to $d(t) = \frac{m}{k}*\ln(\cosh(\sqrt{\frac{mg}{k}} * t))$

Although I don't believe you need them, but $m=75$ $g=9.8$ and $k=0.2$

Comment: The result doesn't change but, for completeness, $v(t) =\sqrt{\frac{mg}{k}}\tanh(\sqrt{\frac{mk}{g}} * t)$ .

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

We have

$$\tanh x=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}$$

so that

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\tanh x=1$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. If the answer was not useful to warrant an up vote, I am happy to delete.